# MacBook Air A1465 screen black and full of multi coloured lines how can I fix this?

Tags: screen

has horizontal and vertical lines flickering and then screen starts rolling
nothing is displayed tried cmd opt rp still not working help!

Comment: Since when has this occurred? Did you drop it...?

Comment: It sounds like a **physical problem** with either your LCD or your GPU.  The only way to diagnose this is to take it in.

Comment: Your logic board needs to be replaced. It's a known hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

Run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) to check if there are any issues, but these seems almost certainly like a hardware issue. Take your computer in and have it looked at by an Apple authorized service provider.